# Show that two sums are equal

Tags: binomial-theorem

Show that
$\sum_{k=0}^4\left(1+x\right)^k$ = 
$\sum_{k=1}^5 \left(5 \choose k\right)x^{k-1}$

I assume that this has something to do with the binomial theorem and a proof of that. But I can't take the first steps...

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Two polynomials with degree $4$ are equal if they have the same values in $5$ points.

Comment: It took me a moment to realize that I should reduce the case to degree $1$ polynomials and then reverse...

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Believe me I didn't know this hint before. :) Is there any online source you can suggest me. Thanks +1

Comment: @B.S. The proof is simple: If $P$ and $Q$ are these polynomials then $P-Q$ is a polynomial with degree less or equal $4$ and has $5$ roots but by the fundamental theorem of algebra every non zero polynomial has exactly as much of roots as its degree hence $P-Q=0$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Now I see that clear. Thanks dear brother.

Answer (score 3):

The LHS is  a finite Geometric Series with the first term$=1,$ common ratio $=(1+x)$ and the number of terms $=5$

So, the sum is $$1\cdot\frac{(1+x)^5-1}{1+x-1}$$

Please expand using Binomial Expansion and cancel out $x$  to find it to be same as the RHS

Comment: There is no valid reason why it should not be generalized to any natural number $n$

Comment: I suggest a quick spell-check, including "frist"...

Comment: @abiessu, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Expanding $(1+x)^4$ is not hard, but how to relate that to RHS?

Comment: @iveqy, expand to find $$\frac{\sum_{1\le r\le5}\binom5rx^r}x=\cdots$$